# Visual Studio Teams API giving 203 for 1 company

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an API call which gets projects from Visual Studio Team Services. It works fine for all companies except for this one company which it returns 203 on all projects and task calls. It returns the correct values on profile calls.

Comment: I'd suspect that this organisation has been configured to use the New URL format and you're accessing it with the old format. (`https://org.visualstudio.com/` vs `https://dev.azure.com/org`).

Comment: actually it turned out that the user belonged to two organizations and when the token was authorized it was done while logged into the other organization

Comment: That makes sense too :)